# Civisualize - How does it work and what are the charts showing?

Tags: civievent, civireport, civisualize

I need your help. I am trying to figure how CiviVisualse works. We would like to improve its current styling etc. To do this, I need to fully understand how the dynamic filter works agains graph lines and what are the measurements for those charts. I have attached some print screens as points of reference for my questions.

[image]

1. What does the line chart represent? It says participant: is this "registrations by date?” for selected events or by event type?
2. What are the different lines on the line graph for Participant Overview chart? Is this event types or individual events based on the dynamic filter?
3. The filter and text at the top get out of sync, and also sometimes the line for event registrations goes out of sync (or there is a bug of some form, in which case how much would it cost to fix it?).
4. Is there any way to hide events that are “not selected” appear in a list at the bottom rather than making the number of their participants 0? Or at least do this if there is an event without any participants.

PART 2: Event detail report - When you want to see summary for specific event:

[image]

1. Chart Line: Is this the number of  participant registrations at a particular date or something else? Is it the cumulative number of participants over the time so in the end of the line you can see for example a total 9 registered participants (cumulative -Trend of Participants for this event over the time based on registration date)?

Comment: in order to allow voting on answers to allow the best to come to top, the StackExchange family of sites require only a single question per post. Could you at least put Part 2 into a separate post? I've asked my fellow moderators for their view, but I think ideally you should post a separate question for each of the first four questions as well, including the first image in each of them. Sorry for the bother, but this is one of the ways that the structure of StackExchange makes it possible to provide better answers than a foru.

Comment: @Domi, I think Joe's suggestion is a good one. As a reward for the trouble, I'll try to answer them fast (or get sid to come and help)!

Answer (score 0):

We've decided to close the question as overbroad.